# Assertion Error matplotlib when plotting a pandas read file using matplotlib error bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am getting the error below when I try to plot the error bar of some data I read from a csv file using pandas `read_csv`.

```
ax.errorbar(x1, y1, yerr = std1, marker='d',color='y', label='y1')
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 5762, in errorbar
xo, _ = xywhere(x, lower, everymask)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 5669, in xywhere
assert len(xs) == len(ys)
AssertionError
```

the code I used is:

```
 ress=pd.read_csv('/path/myfile', delimiter=',',skiprows=[0],header=None,dtype=None)
 x1=ress[[0]]
 y1=ress[[3]]
 std1=ress[[4]]

 ax=plt.subplot(111)
 ax.errorbar(x1,y1,yerr=std1,marker='d',color='y',label='y1')
```

I thought at first that x1 and y1 aren't of the same dimensions so I printed `x1.shape`, `y1.shape`, and `std1.shape` and all of them where `(11,1)`. P.S. `(11,1)` is a correct way of representing my data.

Do you know why I am getting this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you print `x1`, `y1`, and `std1` and show their content here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a little misleading here.  Because you're using

```
x1 = ress[[0]]
```

instead of

```
x1 = ress[0]
```

etc., you're passing `errorbar` a DataFrame (a 2D object of shape (11,1)) instead of a Series (a 1D object of shape (11,)).  This is confusing matplotlib.  Remove the extra brackets and it should work.  For example, we have

```
>>> ress = pd.DataFrame({0: range(15,20), 3: range(5), 4: [2]*5})
>>> x1 = ress[[0]]
>>> y1 = ress[[3]]
>>> std1 = ress[[4]]
>>> ax = plt.subplot(111)
>>> ax.errorbar(x1,y1,yerr=std1.values,marker='d',color='y',label='y1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
    assert len(xs) == len(ys)
AssertionError
```

but

```
>>> x1,y1,std = ress[0], ress[3], ress[4]
>>> ax = plt.subplot(111)
>>> ax.errorbar(x1,y1,yerr=std1.values,marker='d',color='y',label='y1')
<Container object of 3 artists>
```

[image: example errorbar plot]